# relative layouts in java code

Tags: android, xml, visibility, android-relativelayout

I am trying to do a small code having a condition that if the Boolean value set true only all the three relatives should appear in the User Interface. If it is set false, only two layouts should be display. I am able to do this.

My problem is when I am checking the condition and set the `View.INVISIBLE` condition to the layout2, the gap is appearing between the layouts 1 and 3. 
How can I remove this gap? My layouts are created in XML like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"                    
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rl_two"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:layout_below="@+id/rl_one"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_two"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have to use View.GONE in place of View.INVISIBLE .

Answer (score 1):

Do 2 changes in your code

1. `layout_height="wrap_content"` in xml
2. replace `View.INVISIBLE` with `View.GONE`

If you are using `View.INVISIBLE` then your View is only INVISIBLE but you can see gap between your UI and if you use `View.GONE` then your UI looks without any gap :)